# Is there a way to generate an object from another object by taking all its properties with except of one?

Tags: javascript, object, ecmascript-6

Having the initial object of this shape:

```
const initial = { a: 'a', b: 'b', c: 'c', d: 'd', ..., z: 'z' };
```

The result should contain all properties but without 'b' for example. I know there is a method like

```
const result = (({ a, b, c, d, ..., z }) => ({ a, c, d, ..., z }))(initial)
```

but in the case of an object with too many properties it's too much code.

Is there a shorter way to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Object.entries()` to convert the object to an array. Use `filter()` to skip that element of the array. Use `Object.fromEntries()` to convert that result back to an object.

```
const result = Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(initial).filter(([key, value]) => key != 'b'))
```

You can also use destructuring. List all the properties you want to remove explicitly in the destructuring target, then combine the rest into a new object with `...`.

```js
const initial = { a: 'a', b: 'b', c: 'c', d: 'd', z: 'z' };
const {b, ...result} = initial;
console.log(result);
```

Comment: I think the second solution is the best, if there are more properties to be removed you just have to add them in `{b, c, d, ...result }` while for the solution which uses `delete` it must be added one line for each of the properties `delete result.property_name`.

Comment: If either of these solutions is working while your original code in the other question doesn't, I suspect the problem was due to you modifying the original object rather than making a copy first.

Comment: you're right. but why isn't it allowed to modify the original one?

Comment: It depends on what the framework does with `myObject` after calling your `onSubmit()` function.

Answer (score 4):

Clone the object and delete the property:

```
const result = {...initial};
delete result.b;
```

Comment: This seems to be what he tried in his [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72821700/create-and-delete-a-property-on-an-object-in-react-doesnt-work) and he said it didn't work.

Comment: Mmh. I don't see a reason why a property can't be deleted when it was created via normal assignment.

Comment: Me, either. I don't know why his code in the other question doesn't work. I suspect it's a different problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can copy the object, then delete a key:

```
const initial = { a: 'a', b: 'b', c: 'c', d: 'd', ..., z: 'z' };
const result = {...initial}; // copy the array
delete result.b;
```

Comment: this duplicates the answer from felix kling

Comment: @jasie I wrote this at the same time as him (no answers when I started to write). I'm knew to stackoverflow, should I delete my answer?

Comment: Ha sorry :-D I think so, yes, he was 2 minutes faster.